# Keras.Sequential model throws " TypeError: Model.compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self' " when using model.compile()

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have been following some tutorials on TensorFlow and have run into a problem with my model that I can't find an answer to online.

I have this code that tries to create a convolutional neural network and then set its compile setting:

```
cnn = keras.Sequential
([
    #cnn
    layers.Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu", input_shape=(32,32,3)),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    layers.Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(3,3), activation="relu"),
    layers.MaxPooling2D((2,2)),

    #dense
    layers.Flatten(),
    layers.Dense(64, activation="relu"),
    layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])

cnn.compile(
    optimizer = "adam", 
    loss      = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", 
    metrics   = ["accuracy"]
    )
```

Whenever I run this code the error
`TypeError: Model.compile() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` gets thrown on the line `cnn.compile(`.

I have tried using the .compile code from another program that I know for sure works, but it still threw the error. So my guess is that there is a problem with how I create cnn. I have also looked into the debugger, and it shows that it recognizes that cnn has a .compile method.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Edit: changing the declaration from

```
cnn = keras.Sequential
([
```

to

```
CNN = keras.Sequential(
   [
```

fixed the issue.

Apparently the parenthesis needs to be on the same line to call on the initializer. Thank you xdurch0!

Comment: Error says something simple to modify the compile line to:                                                           cnn.compile(self, optimizer = "adam", loss = "sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics   = ["accuracy"] )

Comment: Whitespace and line breaks are important in Python. Your code does not do what you think it does. You are assigning `cnn = keras.Sequential` and that's it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the answer **@xdurch0** and for confirmation by **@Lorvarz**. (posting the comment in the answer section for the benefit of the community)

> Whitespace and line breaks are important in Python. Your code does not
> do what you think it does. You are assigning cnn = keras.Sequential
> and that's it.

changing the declaration from

```
cnn = keras.Sequential
([
```

to

```
CNN = keras.Sequential(
   [
```

fixed the issue.